# What are these diagonal flickering black stripes on my Panasonic G7's LCD?

Tags: panasonic-lumix, overexposure, rear-lcd

Why are there flickering black diagonal lines on my LCD display when I am taking a photo, but my actual photo is fine when I looked at it on my MacBook?

Examples on the right side of the LCD screen of my Panasonic G7:

[image: Black stripes flickering at the right side of the monitor]

Answer (score 5):

These are called "Zebra stripes" and basically warn you that using the current settings, the area they cover is going to be exposed over a certain threshold. This threshold is usually 100% (which means "clipped to white"), but this camera actually allows you to customise the levels - documented on page 220 of the [user manual](http://file:///C:/Users/Kamen/Desktop/manuals/DMC-G7_Operating_Instructions_for_advanced_features.pdf).

In this example, since exposure is evaluated for the desk and the things on it and since the laptop screen is in frame and far brighter than the other things, the camera warns you that it would overexpose the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, i'm completely a beginner so i don't know much a about that, but i think . i set it to zebra line 2 and set the thing to 0 to something instead or the default 16 to something, do i need to turn it back or just leave it like that?